# Am I sending a response right in my Azure serverless function?

Tags: azure, httprequest, httpresponse, serverless, amazon-pay

I have a serverless function that is receiving IPN notifications from Amazon Pay. It is http triggered. The IPN system sends a post request and requires a 200 response or it keeps sending the same request over and over. This seems to be happening to me, however I thought I was returning a 200 response correctly. This is my binding in function.json:

```
{ "type": "http", "direction": "out", "name": "res" }
```

And this is a snippet of my javascript in the function:

```
context.res = { status: 200, body: 'Thanks' }

context.done();
```

Anytime before I call context.done() I set the res to 200. Is this a proper way to ensure I am sending a 200 response to Amazon's IPN service when they send a request to my function? Or is there another way I need to do it?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the Azure function work at all?  If you test post to it (use Postman), do you get an 200 response?  Or is the problem intermittent?  Azure functions DO take some time [scale](https://mikhail.io/2017/08/azure-functions-are-they-really-infinitely-scalable-and-elastic/).  Is it possible that it only happens under high load?  How long does the IPN system wait to receive the 200 response before it retries?   Have you checked the Azure Function logs for any exceptions?  Thanks.

Comment: The function works, Postman returns a 200 response with my body. I don't know about high load but I should test that. The docs for the IPN system only say to send an immediate response. I am using an SDK to parse the IPN message. Maybe they aren't receiving the responses fast enough sometimes? The problem is intermittent. Function logs look as expected if it was working. Maybe I need to send a response immediately before I process the request, but being new to Azure I am unsure how to do that without calling context.done(). I will look into that

Comment: Zombie post, but still wondering if you ever figured this one out?  Find any answers?  If it helps, to immediately respond with a 200 you could wrap your Azure Function in an Azure LogicApp.  Let the Logic App respond 200. After responding it could call your Azure Function.

Comment: @TroyWitthoeftI did figure it out! But I don't remember how. I think it had to do with older tests I had made before I was sending the response the right way, and those older tests were sending the requests and eventually died out. Thanks for your input! If I had a more robust need I'd reach for the app wrapper solution.